# React acting weird in StrictMode: render ignored, state unchanged

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I've used React for years but never saw such confusing behavior before. I know `StrictMode` renders components twice, but it's acting much weirder than usual and breaks my component.

My component is called `Await`. It renders a `children` function when a `promise` completes. So when I run this:

```
let root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById('root')!
);
root.render(<StrictMode><App/></StrictMode>);

function App() {
    return (
        <div>
            Async
            <Await
                //deps={[0]}
                promise={new Promise<string>(
                    (ok, rej) => setTimeout(() => ok('data'), 3000))}
                fallback={<div>Loading....</div>}>
                {x => <div>Done loading {x}</div>}
            </Await>
        </div>);
}
```

It should say "Async Loading..." for three seconds and then "Async Done loading data". Under `StrictMode`, **it does render** (twice) after the promise is completed, but neither of the *outputs* from the two renders show up on the screen. Note that there's an optional `deps` array that behaves like the DependencyList in standard hooks; the problem occurs with or without this feature. By adding some `console.log`s, I notice something very odd...

```
export interface AwaitProps<T> {
    /** A promise to wait for (or a function that returns a promise).
     *  If the promise varies on each render of your outer component,
     *  it is recommended to use `deps` or else `Await` cannot render `children`
     *  until the last promise completes. */
    promise: PromiseLike<T> | T | (() => PromiseLike<T> | T);
    /** This is rendered when `promise` hasn't resolved/failed yet. If not provided,
     *  a default fallback (controlled by `DefaultAwaitFallback`) is shown. */
    fallback?: React.ReactElement | (() => React.ReactElement);
    /** Render method called when `promise` resolves successfully */
    children: (data: T) => React.ReactElement;
    /** Render method called when `promise` fails. If this is not provided, 
     *  the error is thrown and you should have an error boundary to catch it. */
    onError?: (error: any) => React.ReactElement;
    /** If this is provided, the `promise` is only used on first render or when 
     *  `deps` changes. This prop also requires `fallback` to be provided (because 
     *  it relies on `useRef` to return the same ref every time, which doesn't 
     *  happen when using React Suspense). IMPORTANT: This must be provided either 
     *  on every render, or never. React will malfunction if you alternate between
     *  an array and `undefined`. */
    deps?: React.DependencyList;
}

export const DefaultAwaitFallback = React.createContext(<div>Loading...</div>);

export function Await<T>(p: AwaitProps<T>): React.ReactElement {
    let defaultFallback = React.useContext(DefaultAwaitFallback);
    let p_promise: any = p.promise;

    // If p.deps is provided, consider using an older value of `p.promise`
    if (p.deps) {
        let promiseRef = React.useRef<any>(); // eslint-disable-line react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
        let depsRef = React.useRef<any>();    // eslint-disable-line react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
        if (!promiseRef.current || !areDepsEqual(p.deps, depsRef.current)) {
            promiseRef.current = typeof p_promise === 'function' ? p_promise() : p_promise;
            console.log('??? Saving promise ', getId(promiseRef), getId(promiseRef.current), promiseRef.current, 'deps:', p.deps, depsRef.current);
            depsRef.current = p.deps;
        }
        p_promise = promiseRef.current;
    }

    // Get (or prepare to get) the status of the promise
    let promise = typeof p_promise === 'function' ? p_promise() : p_promise;
    let [state, forceUpdate] = React.useState(0);
    let result: PromiseStatus<T>;
    if (!promise?.then) {
        result = { _status: promise, _result: promise as T };
    } else if ('_status' in promise) {
        result = promise;
    } else {
        console.log('??? Augmenting promise id', getId(promise));
        // Augment the raw promise with result info
        result = promise as PromiseStatus<T>;
        result._status = 'pending';
        promise.then(
            (value: T) => {
                console.log('??? resolved OK', getId(result), value, '| setState', state + 1);
                result._status = result._result = value;
                forceUpdate(state + 1);
            },
            (error: any) => {
                result._status = result._error = error,
                forceUpdate(state + 1);
            },
        );
    }

    console.log('??? Await status', result._status, '| state ==', state, '| promise id', getId(promise));

    if ('_error' in result) {
        if (p.onError) {
            return p.onError(result._error);
        } else {
            throw result._error; // Throw to error boundary
        }
    }
    
    if ('_result' in result) {
        console.log('??? Await OK', getId(promise), result._result);
        return p.children(result._result!);
    }

    console.log('??? Await Fallback', p.fallback);
    return (typeof p.fallback === 'function' ? p.fallback() : p.fallback) ?? defaultFallback;
}

interface PromiseStatus<T> {
    _status: 'pending'|T|any;
    _result?: T;
    _error?: any;
}
```

(The console logs use `getId` to get an ID number for the objects involved; code for that and `areDepsEqual` is below.)

As I understand it, the console logs displayed in Firefox use two colors, white for the "main" render, which happens first and gray for the "fake" `StrictMode` render.

[image: console output]

As you can see, calling `forceUpdate` apparently causes a pair of re-renders, but not only does this not work, the state wasn't updated to 1 like it should have been. (I typed 'waiting' during the 3-second wait). Also, if I change it to `useReducer(f)` instead of `useState`, the reducer function `f` is never called.

So.... ideas? By the way, it looks like this without StrictMode:

[image]

React version: 18.2.0

```
// for reference
let nextObjectId = 1;
let objectIds = new WeakMap<{}, number>();
(window as any).__objectIds = objectIds;

/** Gets a unique ID number to identify an object */
export function getId(object: {}): number;
export function getId(object: {} | null | undefined): number | undefined;
export function getId(object: {} | null | undefined) {
    if (object != null) {
        let id = objectIds.get(object);
        if (id === undefined) {
            objectIds.set(object, id = nextObjectId++);
        }
        return id;
    }
}

function areDepsEqual(deps?: React.DependencyList, prevDeps?: React.DependencyList) {
    if (!deps || !prevDeps || deps.length !== prevDeps.length) {
        return false;
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < prevDeps.length; i++) {
        if (!Object.is(deps[i], prevDeps[i])) {
            return false;
        }
    }
  
    return true;
}
```